# pgRouting: How to get other edge attributes

Tags: python, postgis, pgrouting, osm2pgrouting

I have imported some OSM data in a PostGIS database (using osm2pgrouting) to use with pgRouting. I use Python to send the SQL queries. It works fine, however I noticed that the result includes many edges with the same ID. For example this is the results I get for a simple routing query:

```
   seq  path_seq   node      edge      cost  agg_cost
0    1         1   7215  30893710  0.001981  0.000000
1    2         2   7216  30893710  0.001536  0.001981
2    3         3   7221  30893710  0.001988  0.003517
3    4         4   7222  30893710  0.003713  0.005505
4    5         5   1928  19845569  0.002535  0.009218
5    6         6  12145        -1  0.000000  0.011753
```

It seems many edges between the two vertices have the same edge ID=30893710. However, the gid or osm_id that are also available in the table are unique. How can I return these attributes along with the "default" attributes returned by e.g. pgr_dijkstra? Ideally, even the geometry field the_geom?

Here is the code I use:

```
import sqlalchemy as db
import pandas as pd

engine = db.create_engine('postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/mytable')

query = "SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT osm_id AS id, source, target, cost FROM ways', 7215, 12145);"
res = pd.read_sql_query(sql=query, con=engine)
print(res)
```

Comment: double check the `oms_id` uniqueness in your table... because in OSM, it is **not** meant to be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OSM data doesn't necessarily have a valid network topology to be usable with pgRouting. Therefor `osm2pgouting` fixes the network topology if necessary.

It keeps the `osm_id` for reference, but you shouldn't use this as ID in your shortest path query.

According to your code sample this is your query:

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT osm_id AS id, source, target, cost FROM ways', 7215, 12145);"
```

But you shouldn't use `osm_id AS id`. You should use the serial ID of your `ways` table as ID, like:

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT gid AS id, source, target, cost FROM ways', 7215, 12145);"
```

Comment: I see now, it works, thanks!